# PostgreSQL will stop logging when logrotate rotate postgresql log file

Tags: postgresql, log

I have installed

```
PostgreSQL 10.6 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3), 64-bit
```

And configured:

```
log_filename = 'postgresql.log'
```

But I would like to manage log rotations by logrotate instead of internal logrotation by PostgreSQL:

```
#vim /etc/logrotate.d/postgresql

/var/lib/pgsql/data/log/postgresql.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    compress
    create 0664 postgres postgres
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
}
```

Where logrotate works as expected but PostgreSQL will stop logging into the rotated `/var/lib/pgsql/data/log/postgresql.log` file. The only resolution is to `systemctl restart postgresql` which could be placed inside logrotate `postrotate/endscript` block but I can't do it this way if this is done on critical production system.

Do you have any advice how to properly logrotate PostgreSQL log file without need of restarting PostgreSQL?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
During reloading of PostgreSQL it looks for changes. I found a workaround how to achieve that PostgreSQL will start to log into rotated *postgresql.log* file - I need to modify config file, for example comment out/modify *log_filename* then reload PostgreSQL and revert changes back and reload PostgreSQL again. Because PostgreSQL looks for changes in configuration file. But I would be glad if there is another better solution than touching configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my actual workaround using **sed**:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data/log/postgresql*.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    create 0664 postgres postgres
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        sed -i "s/log_filename = 'postgresql.log'         # log file name pattern,/log_filename = 'postgresql_rotate.log'         # log file name pattern,/" /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
        systemctl reload postgresql
        sleep 1
    endscript
    postrotate
        sed -i "s/log_filename = 'postgresql_rotate.log'         # log file name pattern,/log_filename = 'postgresql.log'         # log file name pattern,/" /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
        systemctl reload postgresql
    endscript
}
```

Where line

```
log_filename = 'postgresql.log'         # log file name pattern,
```

Will be temporarly renamed to **postgresql_rotate.log**, reload PostgreSQL and after rename log file back to **postgresql.log** and then reload PostgreSQL again.

**delaycompress** is there because of **postgresql_rotate.log** which needs to be there to properly rotate remporary rotate log file. If we will just comment out *log_filename* PostgreSQL will create log file named by actual time and this can be never rotated because it changes name each rotation. So first 2 files will be kept uncompressed and all others compressed.

I would be glad if you could find more better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`copytruncate` directive](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) of logrotate if you can accept the small risk of losing log data.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has the old log file open and keeps writing to it. Renaming the file doesn't change that.

Try to add a `postrotate` command that calls

```
pg_ctl reload -D /path/to/datadir
```

or uses some other way to send a signal 1 to the postmaster.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thank you for reply. I tried to add mentioned command into postrotate section but PostgreSQL behaves same way - it won't start logging into new file. I tried it even from database by running **SELECT pg_reload_conf();** or **systemctl reload postgresql** but still no luck.

Comment: I verified now:
Message during reloading will appear: _pid=[7211]: session=[8-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  received SIGHUP, reloading configuration files_
and will be written into actual log but future events are still written into older one if was rotated. So it's still wiring into old file even it was postroated.

Comment: Hm, yes, I just read the code, and the file is only rotated if the parameters `log_directory` or `log_filename` change. So you cannot use logrotate that way unless you are willing to restart PostgreSQL. Ise the built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled to find many references in the postgres docs, but you can call an [admin function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE) to rotate the logs:

```
select pg_rotate_logfile()
```

In more recent postgres the same code can also be triggered by putting a `logrotate` signal file inside the `$PGDATA` folder.

```
touch /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/logrotate
```

This allows for moving the log file and then triggering postgres to start writing to a new one afterwards:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data/log/postgresql.log {
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    postrotate
        touch /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/logrotate
    endscript
}
```